# dompdf creating pdf

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

Is there a way to make dompdf see a CSS file to style the PDF output? Or does it have to be inline with a style attribute like `style="border:...;"`?

Here's what I tried:

```
require_once("pdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
$html = ob_get_contents();
//ob_clean();
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->set_base_path(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
$dompdf->render();
$content = $dompdf->output();
$fileatt = "generated_pdfs/mypdfss.pdf";
file_put_contents($fileatt, $content);
```

Comment: Did you try to insert it into `$html`?

Comment: Yeah I tried through <style> in head but it didnt work

Comment: Show the code and the final html page. I'm using dompdf in a few projects and do not have problems with css styles.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> 
<title>Invoice</title> 
<style> 
body { 
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.bodyTextLarge {
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #666666;
}
</style> 
</head>

Comment: Do you want to say that it is not applied? Try to change to background color to see the result. `did you put it in like this? ` yes, style block in the head section.

Comment: Put your solution as an answer below and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you are trying to use styling for elements or selectors that are above CSS 2.1 (which dompdf currently supports). You can check this[documentation](https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/CSSCompatibility) to verify whether the styling is supported.